# Layout like radial menu

Tags: android, layout

I have to design something like this and add click event for each block,how should I proceed for that.Could anyone guide me regarding this

[image: Layout]

Comment: Hi; What is your minimum SDK version?

Comment: @ mohammad jannesary 8

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android) also

Comment: Hello Pooja, Please share code if you have done this menu.

Comment: @poojagupta Can u share code for this?

Answer (score 2):

I know that's too late to reply but this is for the developers who needs some functionalities like this now onwards in their projects..

Look at this demo Project on [github](https://github.com/beaucollins/radial-menu)

You can make this by own `dynamically` too by using `screen width` & `screen height` , but that would be too complicating..

Better to use the Library or `Third Party` for that..

You can get some of demos like this too..

https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1142

https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1754

Hope that helps others too.