# How to create custom button like the image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen an android app which uses the following button.[image]

And i want to build something similar. How can i do this?

What is it called and how to do this?

Comment: You need to search for `android radial menu`

Comment: @Rotwang : thanks a lot. Can you please post it as an answer, so that i can accept it. I don't know why i am getting so many negative marking for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layout like radial menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375035/layout-like-radial-menu)

Comment: Well, no. mine is not suited for a good answer. But it is a good comment, I guess. Requesting for tutorials, libraries or other off-site resource is off-topic, here. Hence, such a question easily becomes a downvote-magnet.

Comment: But this is supposed to be a site to help each other and it can happen that some one is willing to learn and might not know about a simple thing. Aren't we suppose to be helping them? Plus its not a simple design that anyone will know. Only providing the name helps a lot sometimes. Thanks a lot Rotwang.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Radial menu for this purpose.

Look at this demo Project on [github](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android)